# EclipseLink firing find query randomly before getting resultset from createNativeQuery

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

Strange behavior of EclipseLink (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050), I have a false(dummy/not an actual Table in DB) Entity class to hold a result set returned from createNativeQuery(query, entity.class)
    @Entity
    public class VirtualTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ROW")
private Integer row;

@Column(name = "ABC")
private String abc= null

@Column(name = "XYZ")
private String xyz= null
```

Below is my Code to get the resultset
I have set the entityClass to the VirtualTable.class

```
/**
 * Get a list of entity objects by a native query.
 * 
 * @param nativeQueryString the query.
 * @param qryParamList the parameters for the query. Must be in the  same    order as listed in the query.
 * @param entityClass the Class of the entity object. The entityClass    field must be mapped to the 
 *        column names from the query result set.
 * @return a list of entity object of class entityClass
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static List getObjectListByNativeQuery(String nativeQueryString,
        List<Object> qryParamList, Class entityClass) {
    EntityManager em =  ReportRepository.getEntityManager(SqlConstants.PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME_PODR_RPT  );

    //populate the parameter list
    logger.info("em test inside query"+ em.hashCode()   +"                  "+nativeQueryString + ", with ref class: " + entityClass.getName());
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(nativeQueryString, entityClass);

    if(qryParamList != null && qryParamList.size() > 0) {
        for(int i=0; i< qryParamList.size(); i++) {
            Object param = qryParamList.get(i);
            //the native query parameters must start with 1 
            query.setParameter(i+1, param);
        }
    }
    List resultList = query.getResultList();
            return resultList;
}enter code here
```

Before the resultset is returned, JPA is trying to fire the a find query by itself and as this table is not in DB, it throws table not found.
I am using SOFT cache in persistence.xml other than that it is a simple JPA implementation.
Please let me know how can i avoid JPA making this queries for this specific entity class and define that it is not an actual DB table. I want to avoid manual mapping, I am not persisting this virtualtable anywhere, just getting the result set and writing to excelsheet

ERROR LOGS as below

```
  [7/21/16 2:46:43:455 EDT] 0007f794 SystemOut     O 2016-07-21   02:46:43.455 [WARN]     org.eclipse.persistence.session.podr02_user=PODRRPT.internalLog:588@PODRSchedWorkManager.Alarm Pool : 12  -  Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Error Code: 942
Call: SELECT ROW, ABC, XYZ FROM VIRTUALTABLE WHERE (ROW = ?)
bind => [79]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(referenceClass=VirtualTable )

[7/21/16 2:46:43:455 EDT] 0007f794 SystemOut     O 2016-07-21   02:46:43.455   [ERROR]   com.bmo.cm.common.framework.service.AbstReportFileGenerator.generateReportFil    e:88@PODRSchedWorkManager.Alarm Pool : 12  - Exception   [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Error Code: 942
Call: SELECT ROW, ABC, XYZ FROM VIRTUALTABLE WHERE (ROW = ?)
bind => [79]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(referenceClass=VirtualTable )
```

Comment: Show the stack trace as it will point where and maybe why the query is needed.

Comment: i wish I could , in production the logs just filters out exception, and i tried to recreate this scenario in my local but it never happened, eventually i had to programmatically call em.find(virtualentity.class, primarykey) to replicate the issue

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using an Entity for this, as entities require JPA to manage and track changes to them, requiring object identity and caching.  Instead, if using JPA 2.1, you should be using a constructor expression to build a pojo using the [ConstructorResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html) within a [SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html)

Comment: Thanks Chris for your comments, strange thing is that it happens randomly and let say job tries in next 5 mins interval, it will not fire the Find query and no error is encountered.Is there a way to avoid this behavior

Comment: yes - don't use an entity :).  If you keep using an entity, there isn't a way to stop it without pinpoint its cause.  My guess would be it is something related to caching; anything that requires fetching the entity may cause this type of find query, such as some shared cache settings that use invalidation.  You could try turning off the shared cache for this entity if you haven't already